# Making Mutt GPG encrypt emails saved as drafts

Tags: gnupg, mutt

How can I, when postponing an email in Mutt, ensure that the email is GPG encrypted  before it is saved to the drafts folder?

Ideally, this would be based on the PGP setting for the email being composed.

Comment: I'd like to know that as well, it can be helpful if drafts are configured to be stored on the imap server

Comment: Similar question: [How can you let mutt encrypt mails in the sent-mail folder?](http://superuser.com/questions/636705/how-can-you-let-mutt-encrypt-mails-in-the-sent-mail-folder)

Answer (score 2):

Encrypting a draft in mutt would depend on the capability of your editor, which, in the case you use vim, could be solved using the [vim encryption plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=661). Or [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510105/gnupg-how-to-edit-the-file-without-decrypt-and-save-to-local-disk-first) in case you use nano editor.

Comment: Still not enough rep to post more links?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens now I don't remember any more 8-) mhmmm...